# Pygame не понимает символ переноса строки \n

Tags: python, строки, pygame

Сделал скрипт для pygame, чтобы строка переносилась, если количество символов в строке делится по модулю на ***end*** (максимальное количество символов на строку):

```
def print_text(message, x, y, end=0, font_color=(255, 255, 255), font_type='media/FiraSans-Italic.ttf', font_size=30):
    pygame.font.init()
    if end > 1:
        words = []
        for i in message:
            words.append(i)
            if len(words) % end == 0:
                words.append("\n")
        message = "".join(words)
        print(message)
    font_type = pygame.font.Font(font_type, font_size)
    text = font_type.render(message, True, font_color)
    screen.blit(text, (x, y))
```

Но на выходе получаю вместо переноса строки только этот символ - `⍰`, на месте вставляемого `"\n"`

Comment: Текст может быть только в одну линию, символ переноса строки не поддерживается функцией render. Поэтому вам придется рендерить каждую строчку отдельно и помещать друг за другом, что в принципе указано в документации к методу render. Можете сами сделать или же примеры есть на EnSO: [Раз](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42014195/rendering-text-with-multiple-lines-in-pygame) и [Два](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32590131/pygame-blitting-text-with-an-escape-character-or-newline)

Comment: а как тогда можно реализовать в методе print_text перенос текста на следующую строку?

Comment: Рендерить каждую строчку отдельно вместо простого `\n`, делая смещение по координате `y` в blit. В ссылках к первому комментарию есть примеры кода.

Comment: В принципе разбиение текста по максимальной длине решается функциями из стандартного модуля [textwrap](https://docs.python.org/3/library/textwrap.html), после разбиения остается только вывести полученный список строк.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

решил вопрос, изменив функцию print_text()

```
def print_text(message, x, y, end=0, font_color=(255, 255, 255), font_type='media/FiraSans-Italic.ttf', font_size=30):
    pygame.font.init()
    font_type = pygame.font.Font(font_type, font_size)
    text = font_type.render(message, True, font_color)
    if end > 1:
        words = []
        for i in message:
            words.append(i)
            if len(words) % end == 0:
                words.append('-')
            
        message = "".join(words)
        list_words = message.split('-')
        list_length = len(list_words)
        for i in range(0, list_length):
            j = i + 1
            y_i = y * j
            list_text = font_type.render(list_words[i], True, font_color)
            screen.blit(list_text, (x, y_i))
    else:
        screen.blit(text, (x, y))
```

Comment: Хорошо бы ещё пояснить суть изменений

Answer (score 2):

```
def text(x, y, color, size, text, w):
    a = {}
    n = int(((w - x)/size)/0.45)
    k = int((len(text)//n))
    font = pg.font.Font(None, size)
    for i in range(0, k + 1):
        f = str()
        if i == 0:
            for m in range(0, len(text)):
                if m < n:
                    f += text[m]
        else:
            for m in range(n * i, len(text) - (k * i)):
                if m < (n*(i + 1)):
                    f += text[m]
        text1 = font.render(f, True, color)
        sc.blit(text1, (x, y))
        y += (0.5 * size)
    pg.display.update()
```

Comment: Один только код в ответе не приветствуется, нужно пояснять суть решения.